# Are multiple keyboard shortcuts allowed to switch between spaces?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro, osx-spaces

I have an early 2001 Macbook Pro, and like the early 2008 version I had before that I got used to using <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> to switch between spaces (when I wanted to quickly move to an adjoining space, otherwise I used the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Number Key</kbd> shortcut to switch directly to a space).

I recently got an Apple Keyboard to use at work which has a Control key between the Option key and the Arrow Keys, and the spacing is messing me up.  Is it possible to also assign <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> as a shortcut for this behavior in addition to <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> (since I still use the Macbook Pro at home without the keyboard)?